# pass big dataframes as arguments to multiprocessing function

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, pickle

I have a big `pandas.DataFrame` loaded in RAM and I want to cut it in five parts in order to process these parts independently using a `Pool` of workers from the `multiprocessing` module.

My problem is that my `pandas.DataFrame` is so big that I can't pass each part as an argument to my `multiprocessing` function: I get a `pickle` error.

My question is: how can I pass these parts of `DataFrame` which are already loaded in RAM as arguments to my function without explicitly pass the dataframes.

In other words, is it possible to pass some kind of pointer to the RAM adress of each `DataFrame` to the `multiprocessing` function, and not the full `DataFrames`?

Comment: You can just slice the df and pass chunks e.g. `for chunk in df.iloc[::chunk_size]` will return that number of rows you can determine the chunksize by `len(df/5)` if you want to split the df into 5 parts

Comment: @EdChum I think your point is valuable (as usual), but it's not the crux here. This will serialize 1/5ths, but still end up serializing stuff. Conceptually, (at least in other languages), it should be possible to just pass a pointer.

Comment: @AmiTavory it sounds like something similar to a memory map would help here but I don't know whether multiprocessing would accept something like this, I've always thought that multiprocessing will copy the data and I'm not sure you can get around this

Comment: Thanks, @EdChum - I've seen conflicting statements about this. Some point out that in Linux, a child process inherits the memory of the parent, so if there's no modification in the child, then it should be possible to pass this without any serialization at all without shared memory.

Comment: And is there a way to "broadcast" a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: For instance, is there an equivalent to numpy-sharedmem for pandas? Or is it pertinent to use numpy-sharedmem?